# How to make if scroll distance bigger than half img width, than scroll right to next?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

How to make if scroll distance bigger than half img width, than scroll right to next?  (similar [this](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/))
Can anyone show me some clue how to do it?
Should I store each item scrollLet value related index first?

```
var startx, stopx;
$('.scroll').bind("scrollstart",function() {
    // console.log("Scroll Start");
    // console.log($(this).scrollLeft());
    startx = $(this).scrollLeft();
    return startx;
}); 
$('.scroll').bind("scrollstop",function() {
    // console.log("Scroll Stopped");
    // console.log($(this).scrollLeft());
    stopx = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if((stopx - startx)> 400){
        console.log('next');
    }else{
        console.log('stay');
    }
});
```

HTML CSS

```
<div class="scroll">
    <img><img><img>
</div>
.scroll{overflow:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;}
img{width:800px;float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.scroll').bind("scrollstop",function() {
    // console.log("Scroll Stopped");
    // console.log($(this).scrollLeft());
    stopx = $(this).scrollLeft();
    var dist = (stopx - startx);
    $(this).animate({'scrollLeft':Math.round(dist/800) * 800+'px'},500);
})
```

Comment: startx is not defined